# How to set an Expires header for my static assets in Heroku?

Tags: caching, heroku, expires-header

I'm trying to set an Expires header for my static assets server by Heroku, and I haven't found any information on how to do this...

All the information I've found explains how to set the `Cache` header:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000, no-transform
```

and refers to that as the `Expires` header, but that's *not* the Expires header.

When an asset has the `Expires` header set, the browser uses its cached version, and doesn't even hit the server to check if there's a new version.

With the `Cache` header, I'm seeing hits on my logs for the static files that should be cached.

How can I set an `Expires` header, for **static** assets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to set the expires header anymore. For many reasons some legacy some related to CDN, there are more than one HTTP header controlling how an asset is cached. This includes Cache-Control, Expires, ETag and a few really old ones. You don't need all of them. These days, you only need Cache-Control for a reasonably modern browser. Some people like to set Expires for compatibility. But that's kind of over-valued.

To set cache-control, inside config/environments/production.rb, set these lines

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
```